# Want to rework Python and add-ons for Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have been trying to graph with python for some time now. I want to use matplotlib, but have hit so many bumps in the road. Previously, numpy and matplotlib have been installed, but I am stuck with this error: `ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import`. I'm running Lion on Mac. I think I'm using Python 2.7. I have also tried full walkthroughs, such as this as well: http://penandpants.com/2012/02/24/install-python/. After several installation methods like pip and homebrew I am afraid that there's a lot of knotted things going on with python on my computer. And I really don't know how to untangle it.

I am reasonably knowledgeable with programming and algorithms, but I lack the know-how on how all the add-ons such as matplotlib that connect with python or how a text editor that can execute my code like Sublime Text 2 accesses them. So, as much as I would like to aid this asking-a-question process by letting you know what versions I am using, I don't really know how. Any guidance to how python connects to these things would be really appreciated :)

Ultimately, I wish to start from scratch with this whole mess, reinstalling python and then matplotlib from the ground up--but I'm not totally sure how. So, I guess my final question is how do I do that, or if that is just a wrong line of thinking how do I proceed if I want to graph some mathy things with python?

Sorry for the long winded question, I'll appreciate any help even a nudge in the right direction in learning how my computer organizes python on my computer!

Thanks!

Comment: I've found that working in OSX with python and modules is made easier if I sandbox various modules (and python versions) using virtualenv (and I couple that with virtualenvwrapper). This isn't really an answer to your problem, of course, but I share your frustration and only by starting clean with separate virtual environments for different tasks have I maintained any kind of sanity.  Your error, by the way, could come from various problems, including the module not being in path or even from a faulty install.

Comment: You can also check out `https://store.continuum.io` for anaconda python. Comes with the whole scipy suite as a convenient executable.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems and the best solution I found was to use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) for managing python and my installed modules. The things that I particularly like about using MacPorts for this are:

1. You can easily install multiple python versions (with modules separately installed for each installation)
2. You can select which python installation is the default (whether it is one installed by MacPorts or your OS X python installation).
3. Many MacPorts packages have optional variants so you can easily customize how they are installed (e.g., should numpy use the ATLAS library from MacPorts or from OS X) .
4. If you screw up your installation, you can easily wipe MacPorts from your system without worrying about breaking anything (almost everything installed by MacPorts is put under /opt).